# И снова о цвете морей

Tags: топонимика

Есть довольно много статей на тему того, почему тому или иному морю присваивается определённый цвет. Например, как мы знаем, есть море Красное, Черное, Белое и Желтое. Например, кто-то из авторов пишет, что, мол, *Чёрным* море названо за то, что в представлении греков находилось на Севере. Но как тогда быть с Белым морем, которое находится гораздо севернее? Желтое, можно предположить, — из-за цвета кожи азиатов. А Красное? Да и Черное — совсем не черное.
Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть теории о «цветных» названиях морей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статей, действительно, много. И много разных версий. Белое море свое название, возможно, получило от цвета белого снега и льдов, покрывающих его в зимнее время. Но есть и еще одно предположение, которое заключается в том, что название «Белое» море получило от религиозного смысла сферы, то есть небесной. Ведь в семантике белый цвет – это небесный, божественный цвет. Существует гипотеза, что Белое море и его побережье находится на территории когда-то процветавшей мистической цивилизации – Гипербореи.

Черное море получило свое название потому, что в пасмурную погоду поверхность моря темнеет под черными тучами. Тюркские кочевники, заметившие это, дали ему имя – «Кара-Дениз».
Существует и другое правдоподобное предположение о происхождении названия Черного моря. Еще с давних времен было известно, что все предметы, побывавшие в его таинственных глубинах (даже золотые) – чернеют. И происходит это потому, что на глубине более 200 метров морская вода насыщена сероводородом, легко образующим соли черного цвета.

Несколько версий и о Красном море. Согласно наиболее распространенной, биологической, цвет моря определили цианобактерии (лат Trichodesmium erythraeum). Содержащие избыток красного пигмента фикоэритрина и способных вызывать массовое цветение воды. Однако это природное явление случается настолько редко, что заставляет рассматривать и другие версии, например геологическую. Действительно, на некоторых участках береговой линии близко к морю подступают скалы красноватого, из-за повышенного содержания оксидов железа, оттенка. Мореплаватели их и видели. Прибрежные скалы, уходя глубоко внутрь, создавали впечатление красной воды.

Кроме естественно-научных, есть и историческая гипотеза. Греческий историк Геродот в V в. до н.э. называл нынешнее Красное море - Эритрейским, предположительно в честь царя Эритоса (др. греч. ериброа - красный). Провинция Эритрея расположена на побережье Судана.

Есть и библейская версия. В давние времена евреи переходили из Египта в Израиль, путь их проходил через море. Тогда Моисей приказал морской пучине расступиться перед людьми. Пучина расступилась, и люди прошли по морскому дну. За ними по острым камням на дне моря кинулись преследователи, но море сошлось назад, и преследователи погибли. Воды от крови покраснели, и море получило название Красное.

Интересно еще и то, что Красным это море называется только на европейских языках. На иврите Красное море называется Ям Суф, что означает «камышовое, тростниковое». А египтяне называют свое море Вази-Вр, что означает «зеленый простор».

Желтое море названо так потому, что периодически приобретает желтоватый оттенок глины, которой много на побережье.
Первым европейцем, увидевшим воды  Желтого моря, был итальянец  Марко  Поло. Побывал он здесь на берегах моря в 13 веке, там, где в него впадает широкая река Хуанхэ - желтая река. Хуанхэ выносит в море столько мути, что море на десятки километров становятся мутновато-желтым.

Comment: Что до библейской версии, то в Ветхом Завете это море названо Чермным.

Comment: Я  встречал  версию,  согласно  которой  евреи  переходили  "тростниковое  море",  но  это  был  другой  водоём.

Comment: Как могло войско фараона , преследовавшее ушедших из Египта евреев и погибшее в водах Красного моря , окрасить его воды в красный цвет ? Они же утонули , а не были убиты оружием !

Comment: Это же не вся легенда, там внутри был фрагмент, что переходить приходилось по острым камням и скалам(на дне), так что падали, обрезавшись,и гибли все, и евреи тоже, но они меньше,им помогали высшие силы, а вот когда воды сомкнулись,они были красными.

Comment: @Людмила.Если ты знаешь лучше , то спорить не буду !

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, не греков а арабов. Их "компас" был раскрашен в черный, красный, белый и зеленый цвета, который соответствовали Северу, Востоку, Югу и Западу. 
Отсюда Черное и Красное море. Про Белое и Желтое море они слыхом не слыхивали.
Желтое - по собственному цвету. 
Название "Белое" известно с XVIII века, ранее носило множество различных названий, одно из них - "Белый залив". 
Этимология "цветного" названия точно не установлена, но логично предположить, что от севера - но уже в представлении более северных народов (снег, лед, чистота).

Так что Черное и Белое моря в некотором смысле тезки.

Comment: Поддерживаю @behemothus`а . Тут в случае с Чёрным и Красным морями наверняка присутствует ориентация по сторонам света . "Повесть временных лет" упоминает белых угров и черных угров,- несомненно, здесь имеется в виду не цвет волос или оттенок кожи , а север-юг или запад-восток . Точно также арабские географы писали о "черных хазарах" и "белых хазарах" . Есть Белая Русь/Беларусь, но в давние времена на картах отмечалась и Чёрная Русь . Не исключено , что с цветовой маркировкой происходила путаница . Кроме того, то, что для греков на севере, для славян было на  юге .  Чермное=красное(@F.Kazuki)

Comment: Это  же  названия  морей  в  русском  языке.  Поэтому  важно  своё  или  заимствованное  с  переводом,  когда  и  как  впервые  отмечено,  были  ли  другие  названия  и  т.п.  Чёрное  море  впервые  так  названо  турками,  стало  быть  на  русский  переведено.  Может  повлияла  цветовая  географическая  символика,  для  турок  это  море  северное (чёрное),  может  что  иное.

Comment: Кстати, вне  цветовой  символики  стороны  света  у  тюрок,  монгол,  арабов  как  назывались?  А  индоевропейцев  соответствущая  символика  была?

Comment: >Кстати, вне цветовой символики стороны света у тюрок, монгол, арабов как назывались? А индоевропейцев соответствущая символика была?  
  
Мне ни о чем подобном не известно.

Вот из Вики.  
Традиционная закраска южного оконца магнитной стрелки компаса красным, а северного — чёрным цветами является отголоском древних времён. В ассирийском календаре север назывался Чёрной страной, юг — Красной, восток — Зелёной, а запад — Белой. Соответственно этому были покрашены городские ворота в древнем Китае.  
  
Но само упоминание в одном тексте ассирийцев и Китая ставит под сомнение всё содержание.

Answer (score 0):

Черное - северное, красное - южное, синее (зеленое) - восточное, белое - западное, центр - желтое. Так по-тюркски. Кок Орда - Синяя (Восточная Орда. Ак Орда - Белая (Западная) Орда. Алтын Орда - Центральная (Желтая или Золотая) Орда.

Comment: Из вопроса: «Но как тогда быть с Белым морем, которое находится гораздо севернее?» По долготе оно никак не западнее Чёрного.

Comment: В этом есть смысл, но Вы забыли упомянуть, что у каждого народа - свои представления о цветовом соответствии. У Вас же надерганы противоречивые представления разных народов, которые никогда даже и не общались между собой на тот момент, когда эти названия появились. У арабов, например, С-В-Ю-З - это Черный-Красный-Белый-Зеленый. А у Вас - смесь тюркских, монгольских, китайских и арабских представлений. Компас, например, придумали китайцы - поэтому на нем обычно их цвета. Но без синего - это вообще непонятно откуда. –

Answer (score 0):

Писал комментарий - нашел интереснейшую ссылку.
http://www.ruthenia.ru/folklore/berezkin/144-23.html
Там есть все обо всех.

Поскольку ссылки в качестве ответа не принимаются, привожу малый фрагмент про Китай.

> Китай, Корея. Корейцы: Ионова 1969: 172 [центр, В, З, Ю, С – желт.,
>   син. и зел., бел., красн., черн.], 185 [во время засухи дождь
>   вымаливают у дракона; в Сеуле их приносили у четырех ворот (вост. –
>   зеленый, юж. – красный, зап. – белый, сев. – черный) и желтому дракону
>   в центре города]; Концевич 1982a [Сасин – четыре священных животных,
>   хранителей сторон света; у всех китайские прототипы; В: зеленый
>   дракон, З: белый дракон, Ю: красная птица, С: черный воин]: 411;
>   Троцевич 1996: 94 [центр – желтый, это точно китайское влияние],
>   144-151 [ассоциация сторон света с определенными цветами – не раньше
>   танского времени, причем дана не явно, следует из анализа иероглифов;
>   В.: зел., Ю: красн., З: бел., С: черн.; возможно, однако, что
>   китайское влияние лишь оформило тенденцию, присущую самой корейской
>   культуре; так уничтожение черного цвета красным – победа южного Когурë
>   на северным Пуë]; древние китайцы [центр: желт., Хуан-ди, его помощник
>   бог земли Хоу-ту, храм солнца, созвездия центральной части неба,
>   Сатурн, Большая Медведица; восток: зелен., Тай-хао (он же Фу-си), его
>   помощник дух дерева Гоу-ман, ему подвластны громовник Лей-гун и дух
>   ветра Фэн-бо, Юпитер, восточные созвездия, весна; юг: красн., Янь-ди
>   (он же Шень-нун), его помощник дух огня Чжу-жун, южные созвездия,
>   Марс; запад: белый, Шао-хао, западные созвездия, Венера; север: черн.,
>   Чжуань-сюй, храмы луны и повелителя дождя Юй-ши, северные созвездия,
>   Меркурий]: Рифтин 1980: 656; Williams 1974 [не позднее Чжоу небо
>   разделено на 28 созвездий и на четыре четверти; В.: синий дракон, Ю.:
>   красная птица (феникс), З.: белый тигр, С.: Черный Воин (черепаха)]:
>   367; китайцы [сопоставление сторон света с цветами и различными
>   явлениями и объектами]: Гране 2004: 257.

Остальные страны - см. по ссылке. Почему-то пропущены арабы, которых я считаю законодателями мод в названиях многих "цветовых" объектов Средиземноморья и Ближнего (и Среднего) Востока.